# Copy and paste to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a row of data from one sheet to another having run some other macros, however I keep getting the error message that the paste area and copy area are not the same size and shape.

I have tried using special cells paste method but it seems be missing the data from the last 9 columns.

Code:

```
id.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
missingdata.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I need help changing the code so it copies the full row of data and pastes it under existing entries in missingdata.

It seems when it works when I choose to paste in Column A, however it does not allow me to paste from column B

Comment: Can you show the excel ranges you are copying? Are any cells merged? It would help if you attach an excel workbook with a dummy range to be copied

Answer (score 0):

I normally use:

```
Rows(index).Copy
Cells(1,Rows.Count+1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: it has the same issue as my code above where when i paste from cell B2 it misses out the last few columns